# AngularJS - Center the horizontal scroll bar of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a picture that is bigger than the screen and the user is able to scroll left and right on the image. How do I center the image horizontally using javascript or css?

Here is the view:

```
<div ng-show="isLandscape">
    <div ng-if="isSelected(color.code)" ng-repeat="color in colors">
    <img id="fullSwatch" ng-src="{{ images.swatches[color.code] }}" full-swatch>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my directive:

```
colorsController.directive('fullSwatch', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {

            var img = document.getElementById("fullSwatch");

            //swap width and height values because they are before orientation change
            var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
            var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

            var imageWidth = img.width;
            var imageHeight = img.height;

            var aspectRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;

            // fill image vertically
            imageHeight = h;
            imageWidth = h * aspectRatio;

            img.style.width = imageWidth + "px";
            img.style.height = imageHeight + "px";
            img.style.maxWidth = "none";

            var container = img.parentNode;
            var scrollLeft = (imageWidth - w) / 2;
            container.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;

        });
    }
};
});
```

I have tried adding scroll left to the parent div and on the image itself, but it is not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
     position:relative;
     overflow-y:hidden;
}


   #fullSwatch{
     margin:0 auto;
    display:table;
}
```

I also made a Jsfiddle demo for an example using a Google Image
http://jsfiddle.net/x6jDu/
This approach is pretty simple, where any oversized images bigger than the outter div will be centered with horizontal scrolling.Set margin to 0 auto on the image id does the centering trick. Hope this solves your problem.